# What does relative positioning inside relative positioning do?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to swim in this sea of CSS and one thing that I have been trying to understand is relative/absolute positioning.

From what I understand, relative positioning positions the object relative to its regular place while absolute positioning positions the object relative to its closest `relative` parent.

So I wrote some CSS code to try to help me understand this and there is one thing that is confusing me:

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}

.outerdiv {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
}

.innerdiv {
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  left: 400px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv">
  Outerdiv
  <div class="innerdiv">Innerdiv</div>
</div>
```

I found that when I changed the positioning of the `innerdiv` element to absolute, it made no difference. Shouldn't the relative positioning position the inner div 400px right of where it *should be* while absolute positioning positions the inner div 400px right of the `outerdiv`?

Comment: yes and both positions are the same in your case, coincidence.

Comment: I actually also had the left property of `innerdiv` set to `300px` and it was still the same behavior. Is this also expected?

Comment: @Alaska - It is. But try setting `top` on the innerdiv.  Then you'll see a difference between relative and absolute.

Answer (score -3):

When you set the positioning of an element to be absolute, it takes its immediate non-static parent as reference.
In your case, the outerdiv is already non-static, so changing the positioning of innerdiv from relative to absolute makes no difference.